# How do I commit from a repository to two different server repositories automatically?

Tags: eclipse, svn

I have one SVN repository and two different server SVN repositories. I am working in my SVN repository on a project, i am using eclipse subversion. when i commit on eclipse project then this commit In both the server 1 and the server 2 will go to. I can not adjustment on server 1. So how i can do this schedule? or what can i use any tools on Ubuntu.

Note: server 1 Cent-OS server 2 Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you mean : one local **working copy** and two remote **repositories**?  And I cannot understand the meaning of: "when i commit on eclipse project then this commit In both the server 1 and the server 2 will go to. I can not adjustment on server 1. So how i can do this schedule".

Comment: yes it mean like this. I want to tell my, i am working on eclipe project and then this commit will go to server1 and server2. server1 in Frankfurt server2 in Antalya

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have two SVN repositories, and you want them to be backup with each other, right?

In order to achieve that, thinking of "committing to two repositories by one local copy" is probably not a wise choice.

SVN itself already provide a [svnsync](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnsync.html) facility if you simply want to have a backup of your main repository.

If you are looking for a way to let developers from different location to read from a repository from local network, you may consider using the [write-through proxy](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.extra.writethruproxy) facility of SVN

Comment: There are two Development team, one is in Frankfurt other in Antalya. We are developing in Antalya office and using server2. when we change the code , making commit manual to Frankfurt server (server1). we never interfere server1. because this is denied. we want to this way. when we change to local repository , automatically commit will go to both server1 and server2. I found **svnkit** but i didn't understand how can i use this structure.

Comment: @sefodu it can never be done in such way.  Just think of cases that your change is going to create conflict with code in server1.  There is no way that people can properly resolve the conflict.  I strongly suggest you rethink of the collaboration method between your two teams

Comment: it is also strange that you said your access to server1 "is denied" but you want to commit to it.  If you can commit to server1 that means you should have read and write access to server1. If so, why can't you simply use same repository for development?  (and please do not use the term "local repository", it is misleading.  Local repository means something else in SVN.  Please use correct terminology to let people understand your question properly and effectively)

Comment: i changed my grammar, so i found some script for post-commit , pre-reprop-commit in hooks folder, i think will route from my svn repository to server1 and server2 repositories. i will write script and then will be automatically commit. is it possible?

Comment: technically it is possible but it is surely going to cause lots of problem.  Just think how you are going to resolve the conflict.  There is no way you can resolve it.  Tell us why you want such setup and the actual problem you are facing, and let's suggest some workable solutions for you.

Comment: and it is even worse after you changed your wording: When you said you "have a SVN repository", do you actually means a SVN repository or simply a Working Copy?

Comment: When I talk about conflict, it is something like this: assume you have file A in both server 1 and 2, you checked out from server1 and update it to A', and on the same time, someone changed A to A* in server2.  When you expect commit be automatically done to server2 by server1, server1 is going to face a conflict because file A in server2 has changed.  There will be lots of other cases which will cause problem